# How to change a json object via javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to have the user input a jira project to be passed through json. What I have currently is what I have found through other comments but has not helped.

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('scYes').onclick = function() {
   var jiraProject = document.getElementById('jiraProject');
   const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   const url = 'https://jira2dev.cerner.com/rest/api/2/issue/';
   xhr.open("POST", url, true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   xhr.onReadyStateChange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(' "fields": { "project": {"key": "TENX" }, "parent":{ "ID": "1","key": "TENX-410"},"summary": "Test Entering Task","description": "TEST","issuetype":{"id": "5"}}');

        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            if (json[i].Id == 1) {
                json[i].parent.key = jiraProject;
                break;
            }
        }

        console.log(json);
        xhr.send();
    }
};
```

};

I would like to be able to ask for user input, and change the jira parent key based on the entered. This should create a jira sub-task with the parent being the one the user had entered.

Comment: Can you ellaborate what you want to achieve here? Do you want to load a JSON via AJAX? Or do you want to send a change to a JSON to the jira project?

Comment: The string you pass to `JSON.parse()` in the posted code is not [JSON](https://json.org). Because of that, [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Syntax) throws a `SyntaxError` exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to add it in to the code like any other string.

```
'{"name": "John", "age": 30, "country": +"'user input'"+ ,"city":"New York"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `json[i].Id` dont exist... you have something like that `json[i].fields.parent.id`

And your jiraProject has to do the same pattern

You can test here:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Get atention to your json structure; should be something like that >

```
'{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'
```